# ./configure + endless loop

Tags: linux, makefile, configure

Am trying to build/install LFTP in Centos 7 and can't get past an endless loop at ./configure stage. Steps I've taken:

```
% wget http://lftp.yar.ru/ftp/lftp-4.8.3.tar.gz
% tar xzf lftp-4.8.3.tar.gz
% cd lftp-4.8.3
% ./configure
```

Then I see an endless loop of:

```
Enter y or n, or enter q to quit:

Enter y or n, or enter q to quit:

Enter y or n, or enter q to quit:
```

Any suggestions/tips appreciated.

I've tried to use a prefix with ./configure too but that doesn't help.

```
./configure --prefix=/home/admin/lftp
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Can you post the whole output of `./configure`?

Comment: The output is nothing but the loop above. Oddly enough, I can configure this in a different account on same machine. Something in my environment variables causing this perhaps? If so, what?

Comment: Perhaps. Try `env -i ./configure`.

Comment: Actually, scrolling back I now see it must be related to my environment as the following is at top of ./configure output: checking for a BSD-compatible install... 
 
                       Stata 15 Installation
 
This script installs Stata 15 into the current directory.
 
You will be asked questions and then, once all questions are answered,
this script will summarize what it will do for final confirmation.
You may press Break at any time up to giving final confirmation.
Do you wish to continue?  (y/n or q to quit)

Comment: Arkadiusz, can you post your comment as a solution? Then I can mark this as resolved.

Comment: But which one of my comments answer the question ? Did `env -i ./configure` suggestion help?

Comment: env -i ./configure was what helped, yes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the following suggestion helped OP figure out the problem:

```
env -i ./configure
```